# Can I get a userspace interrupt or other indication on PMC overflow

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, perf

Can I configure `perf` so that when a PMC overflows, I get a userspace interrupt or other notification?

That is, usually when the PMC overflows the kernel handles updating the counter, taking a sample, or other bookkeeping that needs to be done, but I'm interesting in receiving these in userspace and taking some action.

Comment: Which kind of action you want to take on pmc overflow? Check man 2 perf_event_open http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html section "Overflow handling" (`perf_event_attr` -> `wakeup_events;    /* wakeup every n events */` with requiring to wakeup you every 1 sample written to ring buffer). You may also check PAPI ([PAPI_overflow](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-PAPI_overflow/)?) and [likwid](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid).

Answer (score 3):

According to [man 2 perf_event_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html), section "Overflow handling" there is `perf_event_attr.watermark=0; perf_event_attr.wakeup_events=1` mode, which may generate events on fd or call signal handler for every sample added to rind buffer of perf_events (in sampling mode like in `perf record`)

> ```
>  watermark    If set ...  Otherwise, overflow notifications happen 
>               after wakeup_events samples.
>  wakeup_events
>               This union sets how many samples (wakeup_events) happen
>               before an overflow notification happens.  
>
>               wakeup_events counts only PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE record types.  To
>               receive overflow notification for all PERF_RECORD types choose
>               watermark and set wakeup_watermark to 1.
>
>    Overflow handling
>
>    Events can be set to notify when a threshold is crossed, indicating
>    an overflow.  Overflow conditions can be captured by monitoring the
>    event file descriptor with poll(2), select(2), or epoll(7).  Alterna‐
>    tively, the overflow events can be captured via sa signal handler, by
>    enabling I/O signaling on the file descriptor; see the discussion of
>    the F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG operations in fcntl(2).
>
>    Overflows are generated only by sampling events (sample_period must
>    have a nonzero value).
>
>    There are two ways to generate overflow notifications.
>
>    The first is to set a wakeup_events or wakeup_watermark value that
>    will trigger if a certain number of samples or bytes have been writ‐
>    ten to the mmap ring buffer.  In this case, POLL_IN is indicated.
>
>    The other way is by use of the PERF_EVENT_IOC_REFRESH ioctl.  This
>    ioctl adds to a counter that decrements each time the event over‐
>    flows.  When nonzero, POLL_IN is indicated, but once the counter
>    reaches 0 POLL_HUP is indicated and the underlying event is disabled.
> ```

There is similar but not exact method of limiting size of ring buffer, for example with `-m 1` option of perf record (tool will be signaled for ring filled for around every 100 samples, with poll on fd). This is also useful to see actual perf_event_open arguments.

```
 $ strace -tttT -v perf record -m 1 -e cycles:u -F 20000 python -c 'print(1)' 2>&1 |less
```

Check also examples https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/ - any recent perf tar.gz, then tests/bp_signal.c or tests/bp_signal_overflow.c:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
 ...
        pe.sample_period = THRESHOLD;
        pe.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_IP;
        pe.wakeup_events = 1;
 ...
        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

        for (i = 0; i < EXECUTIONS; i++)
                test_function();

        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
```